# Verifying search results from Coveo in Sitecore with C# Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, sitecore, coveo

I want to test to make sure a search is displaying proper results..

I've tried the below code with many variations of XPaths & CssSelectors.

```
IWebElement body = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[@class='CoveoQuerySummary']"));
return (body.Text.Contains(searchTerm));
```

I always get a NullReferenceException error. I'm stepping through it so I know it's not a wait issue.

I've tried this method but didn't get very far. (I get the same NullReferenceException error when I debug.)

```
        IList<IWebElement> all = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector(".CoveoResultList"));
        String[] allText = new String[all.Count];
        int i = 0;
        foreach (IWebElement element in all)
        {
            allText[i++] = element.Text;
        }
```

Any and all help would be appreciated!

Comment: The search results from coveo are fetched using Ajax. So you'll need to account for the request to complete.

Comment: I am stepping through it in the debugger... I might need to account for that - but I don't think that's my current issue :(

Comment: webber is right that the DOM is filled with the search results after an XML HTTP request to the REST endpoint. However, the Coveo for Sitecore search page DOM contains the HTML elements you look for even before it is initialized by JavaScript code. I know they are in a div with a `display:none` style. Maybe Selenium doesn't allow you to get hidden elements by default?

Answer (score 1):

```
        var temp = driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("CoveoQuerySummary"), 10);
        IWebElement body = driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("CoveoResultList"));
        if (body.Text.Contains(searchtext))
            result = true;
        Assert.IsTrue(result);
```

The above code worked for me (finally!!!) -- I think my greater problem was/is trying to use (and concurrently learn) the page object model. the 'FindElement' calls above always returned a NullReferenceException if I put them in the PageObject file.  I'm still learning & know this probably needs refactored - but it works.

Any tips are still appreciated!